# android in-app billing sandbox

Tags: android, testing, sandbox, billing, in-app

I'm developing a simple in-app billing library. It works with static responses from google, but now I'd like to test this lib with real in-app products.

I have created a test account and I'm trying to buy a product, but google Play is asking me for a credit card. Is there any way to test in-app billing without using a real credit card (a sandbox environment, fake credit card, etc)?

I have read here that the only way to test this is using a real credit card with a test account (so you don't have to pay google taxes) and once you have bought the product, refund it again, but it seems not to be a very 'developer-friendly' way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope it absolutely **SUCKS**

You have to use a real credit card, then go into Google Play , select **View Merchant Account** and hit the individual order then **refund** to get your money back.

sorry!

Answer (score 3):

As of today (or yesterday) Google has finally allowed "sandbox" testing of in app purchases, it goes through all the steps of an in app purchase except the actual charging of the credit card.
Although you will probobly have to wait for the cancelations/refunds like you did before.

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html?rd=1#test-purchases) and [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html?rd=1#billing-testing-test)

Got this info from my developers console.

Answer (score 1):

... and to add to Blundell's answer, it will take close to 6 hrs for refund to be posted, and then you'll probably want to give it another 6 hours before attempting the purchase.... or else.... Or else, what? Oh, I don't know, something like the "you already own this item" bug/glitch/bane of my existence

Answer (score 0):

You can test in-app purchase subscription using testing accounts. For reference please go through the link-
You may use sandbox testing by adding you testers account to play console. 
Go to the play console main screen--> setting--> search for license testers--> add your testers email-id there. 
Then go to your app release-> go for your beta/alpha release. 
Tap on manage testers and share opt-in URL with testers to accept an invite.

https://cheesecakelabs.com/blog/google-play-iap-first-setup-test-sandbox/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)