# Android In-app Billing "Un-purchase" for testing?

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

My alpha testers can perform in-app purchasing fine.

I want to add an element to an already existing one-time purchasable upgrade. For instance, the one time upgrade already includes "power up A", but I want to also include "power up B" with the upgrade.

Since all of my alpha testers have already purchased the in-app upgrade in a previous version of the app, I can verify that they now have access to power up A and B... but how can I set my alpha testers back to "un-purchased" so I can simply test the purchase process flow without resorting to bogus email accounts or some other rube goldberg work-around?

I see no mention of this at [android in-app billing sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243478/android-in-app-billing-sandbox)

How do I un-purchase in-app upgrades for testing purposes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to Android documentation, the test purchases will be cancelled in 14 days. If you need to cancel them sooner, you can cancel your test purchases using Google Merchant Center. More info:

Read this section:
Cancelling completed test purchases
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: Thanks Kasra. All of my alpha testers actually use the app, and a previous version is in production. Unfortunately, all of us actually purchased the upgrade from the live app months ago. Short of creating a new account on my device, is there any way i can set my own developer account back to unpurchased, for instance? Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot make any test purchases with your developer account. Please know that you can even cancel the real purchase if you want - through the Google Merchant Center.

Comment: Thanks.  I dont recall there being any way to discern my purchase from other, live purchases. Is there? Sounds like the easiest plan is simply to get some more alpha testers, unfortunately. Thanks again!